# Meaning of "I just look out and go" in "Doctors will be, walk a couple of miles every day. And I just look out and go, can't be bothered."

Tags: meaning-in-context, spoken-english

From [a speech by a depressed man](https://www.nationalelfservice.net/other-health-conditions/comorbidity/multimorbidity-depression/) who was told to exercise more:

> And the doctors will be, just go out and do a couple of mile walk every day. **And I just look out and go**, can’t be bothered. Can’t be bothered. Because still in the back of my mind, I think, well if I don’t do all this, and don’t get myself fit, and don’t eat healthy, don’t do that, perhaps I will have a heart attack. And that’s how it is. That’s exactly how it is. And I don’t care what anyone says, you know. (P12, depression, no LTC, male).

I don't understand the meaning of "I just look out and go".

I think that "can't be bothered" means that the patient sees no point in walking each day, maybe due to his depression. Maybe he has the feeling that he wants to become worse, because life has no meaning anyway.

But what is the meaning of "I just look out and go"?

Comment: I read the question and go, learning English is really tough. :) I think it’s “I look out the window and think to myself I can’t be bothered”

Comment: Related question on ELU [Why did Ylvis use “go” instead of “say” in phrases like “Dog goes 'woof'”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/486885/80039)

Comment: In addition to Robusto's very clear answer, the passage is made harder to interpret because the writer has not used quotation marks or italics to indicate speech/thought.

Comment: @dbmag9 I think the style is intentional and conveys something of the state of mind of the author.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes; I'm not criticising the writing, just noting that the stylistic choice has added to the confusion in this case.

Comment: @dbmag9 It also doesn't help that we are forced to read the passage, rather than hear it being spoken aloud, where the meaning of *go* would be easier to identify by the downward inflection

Answer (score 48, accepted):

What you have here is the colloquial use of *go* meaning *say*.

Example:

> She looks at me like I'm a monster and she goes, "You're not wearing that to the mall, are you?" and I go "Why the hell not?"

So your sentence could be rephrased as:

> And I just look out and say to myself, "I can't be bothered."

Citation:

> **go** *v tr*
> *Informal* To say or utter. Used chiefly in verbal narration: *First I go, "Thank you," then he goes, "What for?"*
> <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/go)</sub>

**Additional note**

The use of *be* there is also colloquial. It's usually seen coupled with *like* as in "be like," and it also can mean *say* or *tell me* or *behave or comport oneself in a manner that suggests* ... you get the idea.

Example:

> She looks at me like I'm a monster and she's like, "You're not wearing that to the mall, are you?" and I'm like "Why the hell not?"

[Recent example in the news](https://www.thedailybeast.com/redneck-rave-descends-into-throat-slashing-impalements-and-mass-arrests), (emphasis my own):

> A massive country music festival in Kentucky this past weekend started off on rocky footing: Police found meth, marijuana, and an open bottle of alcohol in the first vehicle they stopped at a traffic checkpoint. One of the people in the car had two active warrants out for their arrest.
>
> “**We were like, ‘Well, this doesn’t bode well for the weekend**,’” Edmonson County Sheriff Shane Doyle told the Lexington Herald-Leader.

Yeah, people really do talk like that. All the time, in fact.

**Further note**

Because there is speculation in chat as to where and when this usage originated, [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=go) has this to say under the entry for *go*:

> Meaning "say" emerged 1960s in teen slang.

No mention of where, however.

**Supplementary further additional note**

It occurs to me that OP was also confused by "look out" as used in the text. In this context I believe it just means to view—metaphorically (the mental and emotional prospect of walking) or literally (the place where such walking might take place)—the concept of walking to cure depression as fruitless when, because of the depressed state of mind, death seems the more desirable outcome.

**And finally ...**

So why do people use *go* and *[be] like* and *[be] all* to mean *say*? Why did these things come into usage and gain in popularity? I believe it's to expand the idea of *say* beyond the merely verbal presentation. I personally see these usages often accompanied by gestures and theatrical expressions (e.g., "And I go, 'Why the hell not?'" said while throwing up one's hands and miming a look of outrage or consternation). Not always, but when they're merely said deadpan they nevertheless *suggest* more of a complete sight-and-sound presentation.

Just a thought. And now I have nothing more to say—er, go—on the subject.

Comment: Maybe my google-fu has deserted me, but I must say I'm surprised that I can't find any earlier duplicate questions about this usage here on ELL. Which until just now I would have said was primarily a *British* informal usage, but I see no support for that position in any dictionaries (or the couple of questions on **ELU** about it, which were easily found).

Comment: +1 Good answer. Reference is made to "be" in "the doctors will be" (there's another occurrence of "be" in the quote). That combines the use of "be" to mean "say" with "will" to make a general statement about what doctors often say, rather than referring to one instance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "go" meaning "say" is definitely colloquial American English (as well as British, I guess) in many American places and subcultures.

Comment: Additional additional note:  "I'm all 'What do you mean?'  And she's all 'Don't you get it?'", etc., is another common form of this.

Comment: Aussies use 'go' like this as well - just ask [Kylie Mole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vnuf9-zgdyw) - (all worth watching for giggles, but prominent use of 'go' kicks in from about 1 minute).

Comment: Someone can correct me if I am wrong, but many a child's English teacher would try to correct this sort of usage of "go" and "be". I thought this should be mentioned in ELL. It's useful to understand what is being said, but unless you are trying to mimic an authentic voice to a particular culture, there is no cause to adopt this pattern.

Comment: @AdamStarrh There's important but subtle distinction between using "go"/"be"/"like" vs using "say". The more casual colloquialisms indicate that whatever dialogue follows is not intended to be a fully accurate recounting of what was actually said.

Comment: @LCooper Sure, but in any case, it is shorthand for a more complete & less ambiguous phrase, such as "I said something like".